# Conditional middleware is always executed

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I have added a custom middleware to my ASP.NET Core Web-API 2.1 application, which  needs to be executed only for certain requests. The problem is, that it is always executed in the pipeline.

***Startup.cs***

```
app.UseWhen(context => context.Request.Path.Value.Contains("AWS"), appBuilder =>
{
    app.UseMiddleware<ValidateHeaderHandler>();
});
```

The code from above completely ignores the condition and always executes the `ValidateHeaderHandler` middleware.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to call the `UseMiddleware()` method on the `appBuilder` object, not on `app` directly:

```
app.UseWhen(context => context.Request.Path.Value.Contains("AWS"), appBuilder =>
{
    appBuilder.UseMiddleware<ValidateHeaderHandler>();
});
```